# how to identify whether xml tag (Element) has childs or not using SAX Parser?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I am new to parsing XML Document.

I'm parsing a xml document and I want to create my own JSON based on that XML File. For that reason I want to Identify the xml tag has childs or not?

I'm overrided the **startElement()** method of *ContentHandler* by extending *DefaultHandler* class.

Code Like this :

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName,Attributes attributes){
    if(qName has a child){
        //perform 1st task 
    } else {
       //perform 2nd task
    }
}
```

Please help me to do this task and guide me if I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If your document is small, using a DOM parser will simplify your task.

If it is mandatory to use a SAX parser then you should also override the `endElement()` method. Then between a start and end element on the same element, all `startElement` events are related to a child element.

Comment: My Document is large so I decided to use a SAX Parser. ok but how can I identify a tag has child or not? because startElement and endElement method will invoke  each time for each Element?

Comment: @ketan--with SAX, you need to do a lot of grunt work, such as trying to find out parent/child relationship... there is no shortcut with sax parsing? How big is your xml file?

Comment: This task I want to do using SAX parser only becoz DOM is good in such a case of large xml file. so is there any way to identify parent-child relationship in SAX? pls provide this solution